# Manually Configuring Windows Installer Settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have inherited a C# software application which has an auto-update component. This component works pretty well, it stops the application, updates any files which have changed, then restarts the application. The software is initially installed using an MSI file.

However what this auto-updater doesn't do is update the windows installer database with the new application version number, nor does it register any new files which didn't exist in the original installation.

Looking at the installer API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx) there doesn't appear to be any way to modify the configuration in this way.

And from what I have read (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx) modifying the registry entries directly isn't recommended.

Somehow many applications manage to accomplish this e.g. Google Chrome.

Is there a way to accomplish this without directly modifying the registry?

If not, can someone tell me (or point me to) the exact registry entries that would need to be changed. Including how to find the guid of the product entry in the installer registry section.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: which component do you use to create your .msi-file?

Comment: WiX but its a direct port from the old Visual Studio Setup Project. How does the MSI creation affect the update mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer updates can be installed with [upgrade .msi packages or patches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's no other supported way of updating MSI's internal registration.

Google doesn't use MSI to install Chrome, so they had to invent [their own patching system](https://code.google.com/p/omaha/).

Comment: Chrome does appear in the add/remove programs list though - so I assumed that meant they use an unsupported way of updating that information? If so then knowing the details of that (without me having to wade through their code) might be the answer to my question. I am also assuming that the add/remove programs list is directly related to the installer database?

Comment: Chrome doesn't use MSI so it doesn't require updating MSI's private information.

Comment: If you add "The add/remove programs list is separate to the installer database" (which I now believe is the case?) I'll give you the answer.